# How to run parallel threads in a for loop (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    thread myThread(compute_mandelbrot, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125, ystart, yend);
    ystart = ystart + 30;
    yend = yend + 30;
    myThread.join();
}
```

I essentially want to run 16 threads parallel, with each thread rendering a piece of a mandelbrot image. I don't see how i can achieve this is in a for loop as i have to wait for the thread to complete before a new thread is created.

Is there a way for me to run parallel threads without having to creating 16 threads one after another?

Comment: Did you try creating an array of threads?

Comment: Create an array of threads and don't join them in the loop. Currently you are creating a single thread and waiting till it finishes in the loop which makes the operation serial and will cause the execution to take even longer that non threaded code because of the thread setup time.

Comment: Why didn't i think of using an array, yeah of course i'll try it now

Comment: related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2009/11/18/concurencyparallel_for-and-concurrencyparallel_for_each/

Comment: joining the threads in the loop makes your code sequential and using threads pointless. You dont have to join them inside the loop. Just have one loop to spwan them and another one to join

Comment: Yeah, i just posted my own answer using the notation and libraries i used in my program

Answer (score 6):

Well, obviously you'll need to run them asynchronously while keeping track:

```
// DISCLAIMER: not a real production code
std::vector<std::thread> workers;
// first start them all
for(std::size_t i{}; i < 16; ++i, ystart += 30, yend += 30) {
    workers.emplace_back(compute_mandelbrot, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125, ystart, yend);
}
// now join them all
for(auto &w: workers) w.join();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create all `std::thread` before calling `join()`, otherwise you are waiting for a thread to terminate before starting the next one.

An easy way to do that is to store the threads in an array:

```
constexpr size_t nthreads = 16;

std::array<std::thread, nthreads> threads;

// fill the array with threads
for (auto &thread: threads) {
    thread = std::thread(compute_mandelbrot, -2.0, 1.0, 
                         1.125, -1.125, ystart, yend);
    ystart = ystart + 30;
    yend = yend + 30;
}

// join everything
for (auto &thread: threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an array of threads using the simplest notation i could use creating all 16 threads and then joining all 16 in another for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++, ystart += 30, yend += 30)
{
    threadArr[i] = thread(compute_mandelbrot, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125, ystart, yend);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    threadArr[i].join();
}
```